# How to know which row in a ListView is selected?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I am working on a simple window form program. The program has a ListView. I need to know which row in the ListView is selected. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [in the documentation of the ListView class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx), there are various properties that start with `Selected`.

Comment: Thanks. I forget to check there before ask.